# Qt override paint method of StyledItemDelegate in Ruby

Tags: ruby, qt, methods, overriding

I'm trying to override the paint method of the QStyledItemDelegate. 
My *CaseDelgate* can be set as the item delegate for my QTableView, but the overriden paint method doesn't get called. 
I'm glad for any help!

```
class CaseDelegate < Qt::StyledItemDelegate
  def paint(painter, option, index)
    puts "hey, I'm inside the paint method"
    super(painter, option, index)
  end
end
```

Comment: you call QTableView::setItemDelegate(new CaseDelegate ()); ?

Comment: Yes I do. Afterwards I tested it by calling QAbstractItemView::itemDelegate() and it returned my custom delegate.